# Find node and that contains empty children using Xpath

Tags: xpath

I have the follow xml:

```
<RiskDetails>
    <RatingSequence direction="O" value="2"></RatingSequence>
    <VehicleDetails></VehicleDetails>
    <RiskFeatures></RiskFeatures>
    <Drivers>
        <DriverDetails></DriverDetails>
        <DriverDetails></DriverDetails>
        <DriverDetails></DriverDetails>
    </Drivers>
    <CoverDetails></CoverDetails>
    <LoadDiscountDetails>
        <LoadDiscount></LoadDiscount>
        <LoadDiscount></LoadDiscount>
    </LoadDiscountDetails>
</RiskDetails>
```

I need to find dynamically every children node without value or attribute. I am trying without success find a Xpath that returns these nodes:

```
<VehicleDetails></VehicleDetails>
<RiskFeatures></RiskFeatures>
<Drivers>
    <DriverDetails></DriverDetails>
    <DriverDetails></DriverDetails>
    <DriverDetails></DriverDetails>
</Drivers>
<CoverDetails></CoverDetails>
<LoadDiscountDetails>
    <LoadDiscount></LoadDiscount>
    <LoadDiscount></LoadDiscount>
</LoadDiscountDetails>
```

I will remove these nodes and keep only nodes and their parents with values:

```
<RiskDetails>
    <RatingSequence direction="O" value="2"></RatingSequence>
</RiskDetails>
```

I could do it hierarchically, however I am trying to do it using only a single Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use below `XPath` to get required output:

```
//RiskDetails/*[not(@* or string())]
```

Comment: Thanks Andersoon, it does work for this example, however I need something generic, I have more nodes before and after this node with different names, I can`t hard code //RiskDetails. Anyway I am trying to play starting from your response.